# QGIS: how to set transparency for OSM tiles layer?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, tiles, transparency-opacity

I'm using QGIS 2.8.3-Wien in an Ubuntu14. My problem is the following:

I'm using the OpenStreetMap tiles to draw maps of some specific regions. The problem is that, for some urban/rural regions, these tiles offer very little information at non-urban regions.

By using the OCM Landscape layer, I can get more landscape information for rural areas, although the infos for urban areas is poorer.

Finally, I though I could merge both layers by setting some level of transparency on it.

However, QGIS does not offer a properties dialog for this kind of layer.

Is there any way of setting transparency for a tiles layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QGIS does not support Openstreetmap tiles natively. I assume you are using the openlayers plugin. That does not allow for transparency.

Alternatively, you can use the `TileLayer` plugin with the ability to set the transparency:

[image]

The tab delimited lines for a text file with `.tsv` extension are:

```
 Openstreetmap  OSM http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png 1   0   19  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0

 OpenCyclemap   OCM http://a.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png   1   0   19  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
```

You can set the transparency in the Properties box:

[image]

---

Additionally, the new `QuickMapServices` plugin offers the same choice, without the need to edit a text file.

Comment: Great, thank you very much ! I would just add that the tab delimited file must have the .tsv extension and utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't found where to set tranparency. The new layers also do not allow properties editing.

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version of the plugin?

Comment: Well, I installed it directly through QGIS. I don't know what happened, but now it works! The properties window opens, with the transparency option. Thank you very much!

Comment: The QuickMapServices (qgis plugin) allows you to set the transparency in the properties (but the OSM plugin does not have this option). This is located in the Web tab in QGIS